# ALTER TABLE SET DEFAULT and DROP DEFAULT are not allowed for tables

Tags: db2

i want to ask one question about db2 sql.
when i runnig this ddl to set default value

```
alter table TTKR.TKR_TableName

   alter TKR_column_name set default '1111-11-11'
```

i am getting this error and search on google i saw that reason is

```
650
THE ALTER STATEMENT CANNOT BE EXECUTED, REASON reason-code
reason code 22
`"ALTER TABLE SET DEFAULT and DROP DEFAULT are not allowed for tables referenced by a materialized query table or view.`"
```

how can i fix it ?

Comment: Drop the view, alter the table, then create the view again?

Comment: thanks, i have solved dropping view.